# Haskell conditional error

Tags: haskell, conditional-statements

I have a problem with a Haskell code, I have the following:

```
takeMeHere cs m =
    |(find (==E) cs == Nothing && (checkNextStep pozxCrt+1 pozyCrt m) == True) = (Just E,[(pozxCrt+1,pozyCrt)] ++ m)
    |(find (==S) cs == Nothing && (checkNextStep pozxCrt pozyCrt-1 m) == True) = (Just S,[(pozxCrt,pozyCrt-1)] ++ m)
    |(find (==W) cs == Nothing && (checkNextStep pozxCrt-1 pozyCrt m) == True) = (Just W,[(pozxCrt-1,pozyCrt)] ++ m)
    |(find (==N) cs == Nothing && (checkNextStep pozxCrt pozyCrt+1 m) == True) = (Just N,[(pozxCrt,pozyCrt+1)] ++ m)
    |otherwise = (Nothing,m)
where
    pozxCrt=fst(head m)
    pozyCrt=snd(head m)

checkNextStep x y m = if(find (== (x,y)) m == Nothing) then True
   else False
```

I get a `parse error on input "|"` . If I write the code with something like if then else if then...it works. But I want to use the | for a more compact coding.What seems to be the problem here ?

Comment: You don't need `== True` ever: if something is True, then checking that it is True doesn't make it more True. Nor do you need `if ... then True else False`, since the condition in the `if` is already a `Bool`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To fix parsing error, remove = from first line. The = sign is put after the guards.

Next, you should indent "where"

```
takeMeHere cs m
    |(find (==E) cs == Nothing && (checkNextStep pozxCrt+1 pozyCrt m) == True) = (Just E,[(pozxCrt+1,pozyCrt)] ++ m)
    |(find (==S) cs == Nothing && (checkNextStep pozxCrt pozyCrt-1 m) == True) = (Just S,[(pozxCrt,pozyCrt-1)] ++ m)
    |(find (==W) cs == Nothing && (checkNextStep pozxCrt-1 pozyCrt m) == True) = (Just W,[(pozxCrt-1,pozyCrt)] ++ m)
    |(find (==N) cs == Nothing && (checkNextStep pozxCrt pozyCrt+1 m) == True) = (Just N,[(pozxCrt,pozyCrt+1)] ++ m)
    |otherwise = (Nothing,m)
  where
    pozxCrt=fst(head m)
    pozyCrt=snd(head m)
```

This will at least parse, yet it won't compile. The `(checkNextStep pozxCrt pozyCrt+1 m)` should be `(checkNextStep pozxCrt (pozyCrt+1) m)`.

Let me add that you can fix a lot of verbose code:

- `find (==E) cs == Nothing` can be changed to `` E `notElem` x ``
- You do not need to compare with True: change `x == True` to `x`
- `if x then True else False` can be changed to `x`
- `[x]++y` can be changed to `x:y`
- You can use pattern matching like this: `(pozxCrt, pozyCrt) = head m` or `(pozxCrt, pozyCrt):_ = m`

The result is:

```
takeMeHere cs m                                                                 
    | E `notElem` cs && checkNextStep (pozxCrt+1) pozyCrt m = (Just E,(pozxCrt+1,pozyCrt):m)
    | S `notElem` cs && checkNextStep pozxCrt (pozyCrt-1) m = (Just S,(pozxCrt,pozyCrt-1):m)
    | W `notElem` cs && checkNextStep (pozxCrt-1) pozyCrt m = (Just W,(pozxCrt-1,pozyCrt):m)
    | N `notElem` cs && checkNextStep pozxCrt (pozyCrt+1) m = (Just N,(pozxCrt,pozyCrt+1):m)
    | otherwise = (Nothing,m)                                                   
  where                                                                         
    (pozxCrt, pozyCrt) = head m                                                 

checkNextStep x y m = (x,y) `notElem` m
```

You have a lot of repetition in the guards. A lot of repetition is a sign to create new functions.

```
move E (x, y) = (x+1, y) 
move S (x, y) = (x, y-1)
move N (x, y) = (x, y+1)
move W (x, y) = (x-1, y)

takeMeHere cs m
    | canGo E = go E
    | canGo S = go S
    | canGo W = go W
    | canGo N = go N
    | otherwise = (Nothing,m)
  where
    pos = head m
    canGo dir = dir `notElem` cs && checkNextStep (move dir pos) m
    go dir = (Just dir, move dir pos:m)

checkNextStep (x, y) m = (x,y) `notElem` m
```

Next step: use `find canGo [E,S,W,N]` to get rid of the guards:

```
 takeMeHere cs m =                                                               
    case find canGo [E,S,W,N] of                                                
      Just dir -> (Just dir, move dir pos:m)                                    
      Nothing -> (Nothing, m) 
    where ...
```

Comment: thanks alot , this is so much better , i am not used with all the syntaxes in Haskell, so i end up writing ugly code that doesn't even work.

Comment: @user1272703: pleace accept sdcwc's answer if you think he fully solved your problem :)

Comment: also , can you please extend the meaning of the move and "->" syntaxes . And what is the main problem with repetition in the guards ? Thank you

Comment: @user1272703: `case .. of ... -> ...` is syntax for case statement, consult a Haskell book. The general problem with repetition (anywhere, not only guards), is that changing code is harder and errorprone, since you have to change several places at once. The software engineering rule is "don't repeat yourself". `move` is a function created to remove repetition.

Answer (score 3):

I can see at least three errors in your code.

- The `=` on the first line have to be removed. The syntax requires a `=` after the guard of each `|`. Basically, the error is saying you that the first pipe symbol `|` is unexpected after an `=` because the latter, in that position, is used without guards.
- You should put parenthesis around mathematical expressions when you give them in input to functions, because infix operators like `+` have a lower precedence with respect to function application. `checkNextStep pozxCrt+1 pozyCrt m` is evaluated as `(checkNextStep pozxCrt) + (1 pozyCrt m)` (which is obviously an error), and not as `checkNextStep (pozxCrt+1) pozyCrt m`.
- The `where` should be indented with respect to the first line.

Unless you have other errors in the code you omitted, this way it should work:

```
takeMeHere cs m    -- no more "=" here
    |(find (==E) cs == Nothing && (checkNextStep (pozxCrt+1) pozyCrt m) == True) = (Just E,[(pozxCrt+1,pozyCrt)] ++ m)
    |(find (==S) cs == Nothing && (checkNextStep pozxCrt (pozyCrt-1) m) == True) = (Just S,[(pozxCrt,pozyCrt-1)] ++ m)
    |(find (==W) cs == Nothing && (checkNextStep (pozxCrt-1) pozyCrt m) == True) = (Just W,[(pozxCrt-1,pozyCrt)] ++ m)
    |(find (==N) cs == Nothing && (checkNextStep pozxCrt (pozyCrt+1) m) == True) = (Just N,[(pozxCrt,pozyCrt+1)] ++ m)
    |otherwise = (Nothing,m)
  where -- indentation
    pozxCrt=fst(head m)
    pozyCrt=snd(head m)
```

By the way, your code is quite redundant, you should do something about all those comparisons with `True` (see @dbaupp's comment on your question).
I suggest you to study a little more Haskell's operator precedence and syntax, It will help you a lot in making your code easier to read :)